# Disable Magento Extension from database

Tags: magento

Is there a way to disable a magento extension from the database?  We can't access our admin area due to a corrupt extension so we can't disable the extension from the admin section..

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If it is a properly created Magento extension, it will have a control file in **app/etc/modules**. You want to use this file to disable the extension as it prevents the module from loading. Disabling in the database allows the code to load but disables its output, an important distinction for something that is causing Magento to fail in its operation.

In this file will be a line, **true**. Change true to **false** and the module will be prevented from loading and executing.

Sample code for module Desitex_Checkoutnewsletter

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Desitex_Checkoutnewsletter>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Checkout />
            </depends>
        </Desitex_Checkoutnewsletter>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to disable a particular extension all you have to do is to change the active block to false. You can use any ftp program which supports file editing to change the extension status to false. Just open  app/etc/module/Namespace_Module.xml in your favorite editor and change it as shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
/**
 * @category   Magik
 * @package    MagentoMagik_Salepro
 * @author     Ashish Nayyar @ MagentoMagik
 * @license    http://www.magentomagik.com  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */
 -->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Magik_Salepro>
            <active>false</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Magik_Salepro>
    </modules>
</config>
```